# How to count RGB or HSV channel combination in an image?

Tags: numpy, opencv, colors

I use python opencv load an image which has shape (30, 100, 3), now want to count the frequency for all the colors, by color, I don't mean individual channel, I mean channel combination. Meaning 3 channel list, e.g. [255, 0, 0] for red, [255, 255, 0] for yellow, [100, 100, 100] for another color. So I want the last axis(channel) to be treated as a whole and count its frequency.

Is there any built-in function in opencv or numpy which can easily treat the 3 channel list as one element and count its frequency?

Comment: So, the output would be an array, right? What must be its shape? It would have a max of 256**3 elements.

Comment: The output can be [[R,G ,B, frequency ], [R,G ,B, frequency ], ....]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with its new `axis` argument functionality that does grouping -

```
np.c_[np.unique(im.reshape(-1,3), axis=0, return_counts=1)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [56]: im
Out[56]: 
array([[[255, 255, 255],
        [255,   0,   0]],

       [[255,   0, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]]])

In [57]: np.c_[np.unique(im.reshape(-1,3), axis=0, return_counts=1)]
Out[57]: 
array([[255,   0,   0,   1],
       [255,   0, 255,   1],
       [255, 255, 255,   2]])
```

Comment: Thanks! Perfect solution!