# How do I histogram a color image using Numpy?

Tags: image, numpy, colors, histogram

Suppose I have a color image represented as a (nrows, ncols, 3)-dimensional Numpy array.  I would like to construct a histogram in which each "bucket" corresponds to a particular (r, g, b) color value and for each bucket, there is a count of how many pixels have that value.

I can imagine how to do this using explicit iteration and a map whose keys are (r, g, b) vectors (or tuples, or lists...) and values are counts.  However, that's inconvenient and probably slow, so I'm wondering

*Can I use numpy.histogram() or some related function/method to do this?*

I tried using numpy.histogram(), but it seemed to treat the 2D color image as if it were a 3D grayscale (voxel) image and count the number of distinct grayscale values, each a scalar.

```
>>> a
array([[[100,   0,   0],
        [100, 100,   0],
        [100, 100, 100]],

       [[200,   0,   0],
        [200, 200,   0],
        [200, 200, 200]],

       [[150,   0,   0],
        [150, 150,   0],
        [150, 150, 150]]])

>>> np.histogram( a, bins = 4)
(array([ 9,  0,  6, 12], dtype=int64), array([  0.,  50., 100., 150., 200.]))
```

Comment: This should help, if not a dup - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320245/.

Comment: Yes, quite helpful.  I'm having trouble understanding what the numpy.c_ function does, though.

Comment: It just stacks the results in columns. Did the solution(s) there solve your case here?